# Should we close RestHighLevelClient (6.2) on every search request ES(6.2)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have scenario, where we do search very frequently. We are using RestHighLevelClient (6.2).

Is it required to close the RestHighLevelClient after every search response?

if yes, is there any performance impact on initializing the client on every request .

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166955/how-to-properly-close-raw-restclient-when-using-elastic-search-5-5-0-for-optimal/46236617#46236617 ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer. But in case anyone is looking for it:

According to [The Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html) the answer is **no**. 
Only close the client when you are

> well and  truly done with it.